# F# "Visual Studio Code" XmlProvider not defined

Tags: f#, visual-studio-code

Compile error:
FSharp.Data.XmlProvider not defined

Windows 10
Visual Studio Code 1.19 64bit
F# 4.0

f# console app targeting framework .netcoreapp2.0

I get an error when trying to use the XmlProvider. Documentation indicates FSharp.Core.dll should support it. Build log indicates fsharp.core.dll being used 
is C:\Users\KAUBUCHON.nuget\packages\fsharp.core\4.2.3\lib\netstandard1.6\FSharp.Core.dll
instead of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.1\Framework\v4.0\FSharp.Core.dll.

My fsproj does not refernce the .nuget\packages... - any ideas? Did configure my environment incorrectly?

sample code below - type definition of XmlProvider fails

```
open System
open System.Xml.Linq
open FSharp.Data
module main =

    [<Literal>]
    let xmlsample = """
        <Customers>
        <Customer name="ACME">
        <Order Number="123">
        <OrderLine Item="widget"/>
        </Order>
        </Customer>
        </Customers>"""

    type inputXml = XmlProvider<xmlsample>
    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main argv =
        printfn "Hello World from F#!"
        0 // return an integer exit code
```

Comment: `XmlProvider` is in `FSharp.Data`. See [the docs](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/XmlProvider.html).

Comment: When asking questions you should include the sample code you are writing.

Comment: Type providers are not yet supported in .Net Core, so you might have more issues with that than just referencing a library

Answer (score 0):

Follow this one: https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/3303

1) Add fsc.props

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project>
  <!-- Type providers currently can't run inside the .NET Core 2.0 hosted compiler, see https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/pull/3658#issuecomment-334773415 -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IsWindows Condition="'$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT'">true</IsWindows>
    <IsOSX Condition="'$([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::IsOSPlatform($([System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform]::OSX)))' == 'true'">true</IsOSX>
    <IsLinux Condition="'$([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::IsOSPlatform($([System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform]::Linux)))' == 'true'">true</IsLinux>
  </PropertyGroup>  
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(IsWindows)' == 'true' AND Exists('C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.1\Framework\v4.0\fsc.exe')">
    <FscToolPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.1\Framework\v4.0</FscToolPath>
    <FscToolExe>fsc.exe</FscToolExe>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(IsOSX)' == 'true'  AND Exists('/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/fsharpc')">
    <FscToolPath>/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands</FscToolPath>
    <FscToolExe>fsharpc</FscToolExe>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(IsLinux)' == 'true' AND Exists('/usr/bin/fsharpc')">
    <FscToolPath>/usr/bin</FscToolPath>
    <FscToolExe>fsharpc</FscToolExe>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

2) Add `<Import Project="fsc.props" />` to your fsproj as subnode of the `Project` element:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Import Project="fsc.props" />

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>
```